# Is insecticide treated mosquito nets against 1st precept?

Tags: five-precepts, dana, eight-precepts, correct-interpretation

As part of my charity action I was going to donate to Against Malaria Foundation. But after reading that 100% of the money is going to buy long-lasting insecticidal nets for the prevention of malaria, I am not so sure if that conflicts with my buddhist practice.

For those who don't know, insecticidal nets are mosquitoes nets that are sprayed with insecticide, which is said to be twice as effective as unsprayed nets.

Against Malaria Foundation website:

https://www.againstmalaria.com/

Wikipedia on Against Malaria Foundation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Against_Malaria_Foundation

> The Against Malaria Foundation (AMF) is a United Kingdom-based charity that provides long-lasting insecticidal nets (LLINs) to populations at high risk of malaria, primarily in Africa. As of July 2016, the foundation has raised $86.6 million and distributed or committed to fund 19.3 million LLINs since its founding in 2004.

Wikipedia on insecticide-treated nets:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosquito_net#Insecticide_treated_nets

> Mosquito nets treated with insecticides—known as insecticide-treated nets (ITNs) or bednets—were developed in the 1980s for malaria prevention. ITNs are estimated to be twice as effective as untreated nets, and offer greater than 70% protection compared with no net. These nets are dip-treated using a synthetic pyrethroid insecticide such as deltamethrin or permethrin which will double the protection over a non-treated net by killing and repelling mosquitoes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is against the first precept since it kills. What you can do is, instead of giving money, buy normal nets and mosquito repellent lotion and donate.

Comment: Yes  - and if you cant do that  or dont want to put that effort  - you have a ton of other causes to donate to  - there is no shortage in stuff you can donate to